# PC Contact Management for Android 2.0

Tags: sync, android, software-rec

I am having difficulty finding any worthwhile software to manage my Anroid (I have a Motorola Droid) contacts on my PC. I want to be able to plug my Droid, sync contacts, and have an interface on my PC to edit/manage all my contacts.

Does any one know of such software?  I haven't located anything useful via Google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motorola Phone Portal is an Android/PC sync app that did not ship with the Droid, but it seems as though it should have.  Not only does it sync contacts, but also SMS, browser history, media, etc and everything can be backed up, edited, deleted, etc.  Below is a link to an article about the app, and another link to a forum post where the app can be downloaded.

http://home.leakdroid.com/2009/10/fresh-leak-moto-phone-portal-for-android-coming-w-sholestaodroid/

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-applications/16622-moto-phone-portal-droid-pc-media-sync-more-via-wifi.html